# sidekiq.yml file is not being considered

Tags: gitlab, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I have installed gitlab community edition on my raspberry pi 3. Everything is working fine. But when the application is up there are 25 sidekiq threads. It's eating up my memory and I don't want so many threads.

I tried controlling by adding the file /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/sidekiq.yml.

```
# Sample configuration file for Sidekiq.
# Options here can still be overridden by cmd line args.
# Place this file at config/sidekiq.yml and Sidekiq will
# pick it up automatically.
---
:verbose: false
:concurrency: 5

# Set timeout to 8 on Heroku, longer if you manage your own systems.
:timeout: 30

# Sidekiq will run this file through ERB when reading it so you can
# even put in dynamic logic, like a host-specific queue.
# http://www.mikeperham.com/2013/11/13/advanced-sidekiq-host-specific-queues/
:queues:
  - critical
  - default
  - <%= `hostname`.strip %>
  - low

# you can override concurrency based on environment
production:
  :concurrency: 5
staging:
  :concurrency: 5
```

I have restarted the application many times and even ran "reconfigure". It's not helping. It's not considering the sidekiq.yml file at all.

Can anybody please let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i found your question by searching for a solution for the same problem. All i found doesn't work. So i tried bye myself and found the right place for reducing sidekiq from 25 to 5. I use the gitlab omnibus version. I think the path is idetical to yours:

```
/opt/gitlab/sv/sidekiq/run
```

In this file you find the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/working

exec 2>&1

exec chpst -e /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env -P \
  -U git -u git \
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle exec sidekiq \
    -C /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/sidekiq_queues.yml \
    -e production \
    -r /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails \
    -t 4 \
    -c 25
```

Change the last line to "**-c 5**". The result should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/working

exec 2>&1

exec chpst -e /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env -P \
  -U git -u git \
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle exec sidekiq \
    -C /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/sidekiq_queues.yml \
    -e production \
    -r /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails \
    -t 4 \
    -c 5
```

Last but no least yout have to resart gitlab service

```
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

No idea, what happening on the gitlab update. I think i have to change this value again. It would be nice, if the gitlab developers add this option to gitlab.rb in /etc/gitlab directory.